# Symfony 3 | Подключение дополнительного кода JS к готовым ассетам

Tags: symfony2, symfony, symfony3, assetic

Добрый день.

В файле index.html.twig у меня есть

```
{% block javascripts %}
   {% javascripts
   'assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
   'assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}
   <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
   {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

здесь находятся основные скрипты.

Но в другом файле я хотел бы вставить собственные скрипты. Каким образом я могу добавить их к уже существующим?

Если бы был просто

```
{% block javascripts %}  
   <script src="{{asset(path(...))}}"></script>
 {% endblock %}
```

то можно бы было использовать {{ parent() }}. Но в этом случае это не работает почему то.

Как должно выглядеть добавление?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в twig добавить ещё 1 блок. В `index.html.twig`:

```
{% block javascripts %}
   {% javascripts
   'assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
   'assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}
   <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
   {% endjavascripts %}

{% endblock %}

{% block additional_javascripts %}{% end block %}
```

А в другом файле:

```
{% block additional_javascripts %}
     {% javascripts
   'PATH/ADDITIONAL/SCRIPT.js' %}
   <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
   {% endjavascripts %}


 {% end block %}
```

Можно ещё добавить промежуточный шаблон допустим `index_with_additional.twig.html`
 в нём отнаследоваться от index.twig.html и переопределить блок javascript:

```
    {% extends '::index.html.twig' %}

        {% block additional_javascripts %}
         {% javascripts
       assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
       'assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
       'PATH/ADDITIONAL/SCRIPT.js' %}
       <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
       {% endjavascripts %}
   {% endblock %}
```

И в файле "другом" файле делать так

```
{% extends '::index_with_additional.twig.html' %}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А может есть возможность добавить это к уже существующему файлу? Просто ассет компилирует все потом в один файл, что мне и нужно. Клиент очень чувствителен к результатам google speed test.

Comment: Добавить -  нет, а переписать можно. Тоесть вы вставляете всё тоже самое, только с дополнительными скриптами.

Comment: И блок javascript будет перезаписан, с предыдущими и дополнительными скриптами

Comment: Тогда первый вариант однозначно лучше. Иначе с добавлением и переписью в итоге каша дикая получится. В множестве мест нужно код вставлять будет.

Comment: или вы можете сделать шаблон с дополнительными скриптами и наследоваться от него в том месте где это нужно (если скрипты дополнительные всегда одинаковые)

Comment: @Владислав поняли, что я имел ввиду или пример добавить?

Comment: буду рад примеру :)

Comment: @Владислав добавил

Comment: То есть, если у меня например будет так, что для вывода меню скрипт, после идет скрипт для слайдера, я должен буду сделать два раза extend. В общем концепцию понял, спасибо

Comment: @Владислав  да, то есть у Вас будет index.twig.html "дед", index_with_additional.twig.html "Отец"